# Is there a correct way to dispose of a httpwebrequest?

Tags: .net, httpwebrequest

I am using a `HttpWebRequest`, and am disposing of the response stream. Is there a correct method of disposing of the `HttpWebRequest`, as it does not contain a close or dispose method?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If the class had special disposal requirements, it would have implemented IDisposable. Since it doesn't implement IDisposable, you may assume there's nothing special you need to do.

Comment: There are scenarios where it doesn't immediately go out of scope - specially when you're creating multiple web request within short period of time. If you do need to dispose of it just cast it to `IDisposable` and then call the `Dispose()` method on it.

Comment: @mee it doesn't matter. `HttpWebRequest` does not implement `IDisposable`.

Answer (score 54):

I had a similar question, and the answers here did not give me the information I needed.  So even though there is an accepted answer, I'm going to add what I've learned to help the next guy.

1) As some of the other answers mention, you can use `using` for the streams returned from HttpWebRequest/WebRequest.  This is just good standard c# programming.

But it doesn't really address the OP's question (or mine), which was about the disposing of the HttpWebRequest object itself.

2) Despite the fact that the function to acquire an HttpWebRequest is named 'Create,' there is no matching Destroy, Close, Dispose, or any other mechanism available to free the resources from the created object.

This is basically the currently accepted answer.

3) But there is an implication among all the answers here that (other than the streams) there isn't anything important left hanging around that *needs* to be closed.  And that is not entirely correct.

Using [ProcMon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx), you can see the `TCP Connect`, `TCP Send` and `TCP Receive` that occur when you call `GetResponse()`.  This is what I would expect to see.  But when does the `TCP Disconnect` occur?  My assumption was that this would happen either after you finished receiving the response, or at worst when the object gets GC'ed.  But the reality is more interesting.

Instead, the TCP connection remains active for exactly 2 minutes after the call.  My first thought was that's just how long it takes for the GC to get around to it, but nope.  You can sit there in a GC.Collect() loop for those 2 minutes, and it doesn't let go until the 2 minutes are up.  This keeps the connection open on both the client and the server, and causes (some) additional network traffic for those 2 minutes to keep the connection alive.

Another interesting thing is that even though you are calling 'Create', that doesn't mean another TCP connection necessarily gets created.  For instance, consider this:

```
static void Doit(string domain)
{
    HttpWebRequest hr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(domain);

    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)hr.GetResponse())
        using (Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                Console.WriteLine(readStream.ReadToEnd());
}
```

Now, if I call this with:

```
Doit("http://www.foo.bar");
```

It will create 1 TCP connection.  It will stay active for 2 minutes (or until the program exits).  But what if I do this:

```
Doit("http://www.foo.bar");
Thread.Sleep(20000);
Doit("http://www.foo.bar");
```

Now it will create 1 connection for the first call, then *reuse* that connection for the second call.  Meaning the TCP connection will stay active for 2:20 minutes total.  So even though we are calling 'Create,' it's not creating a connection from scratch.

Mostly this is a good thing.  Making a connection (especially an HTTPS connection) can be an expensive process.  A system that automatically avoids that for you is (probably) a good thing.  That way you can efficiently retrieve the html for a web page, then any of the related support files (css, img files, etc) without having to go through the connect process each time.

But what if the server you are connecting to only supports a limited number of connections?  Leaving a connection tied up like this for no good reason could be a real problem.  Or perhaps for security reasons, you can't be leaving connections open for that long?  Or maybe you're just anal and want to shut the thing down as soon as you are done with it.

For these cases, you can experiment with `HttpWebRequest.KeepAlive`.  Setting this to `false` (the default is `true`) causes each of the examples above to each use their own connection, shutting them down as soon as you are done.  The entire Connect/Send/Receive/Disconnect process can thus complete in less than a second.

FYI:

- While you can use WebRequest.InitializeLifetimeService to get an ILease, changing the values on the lease does not affect the timeouts here.
- Instead of using WebRequest, you can use WebClient, which does support Dispose.  However the underlying TCP connection still hangs around for 2 minutes even after calling Dispose.

In conclusion: Saying that you don't need to worry about shutting down an HttpWebClient may be generally true, but there are implications you might want to be aware of.  There are good reasons for this behavior, but you cannot decide whether this is good for your particular application if you don't know it is happening.

FWIW

Comment: Thank you for this in depth insight!
I had a complex **REST API** throw random _connection aborted/connection remotely closed_ errors at me. This API (services.mobile.de) is always used in a way where you fire a series of requests at it. It turned out that it doesn't play nice with HttpWebRequest reused connections: It closes the connection whenever it feels it needs to, resulting in random errors. Now that I set `.KeepAlive` to `false`, everything's fine!

Comment: It turned out that the `WebRequest.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime` is important, too: When starting a series of requests, this should not exceed the server's max. idle time, otherwise you will try to recycle a connection that has already been closed server-side, even if `.KeepAlive` is `false`.

Comment: Good ifnfo! Thank you. The underlying TCP connection remaining alive for up to four minutes is more due to the network stack. It is referred to as a "time wait" and it is a normal behavior for the TCP connection to stay open in case the client closes it before the server is finished with it. That way, both ends can close it safely and in a coordinated manner. See StackExchange answer at https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/19581.

Comment: Very informative, thank you. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Why did nobody mentioned that both request and response streams have .Close() method. For requests, one must call request stream .Close and for response either response's Close() or response stream Close().

Comment: I address that in my first point: *As some of the other answers mention, you can use `using` for the **streams***.  Closing the stream is different than disposing of the HttpWebRequest object itself, which is the posted question.

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
    var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(ActionUrl)
    using (var webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
    {}
```

for your implementation.   When I've used the WebRequest class to fire off multiple requests in a very short timeframe, wrapping the GetResponse() in a using block is what prevented the app from hanging up.

Answer (score 3):

httpwebRequest doesn't implement IDisposable since it can create a Stream, which does implement IDisposable. As such, you shouldnt worry about disposing it.

If you are worried though, you may want to use WebClient, which is IDisposable:

```
using (WebClient c = new WebClient())
{
using (Stream stream = c.OpenRead(url))
{
//
}
}
```

Answer (score -3):

HttpWebRequest does not implement IDisposable so it does not require disposing.
just set the httprequest object to null once your done with it.

Hope it helps

Comment: Why set to null? Just letting it go out of scope is enough for the GC to pick it up.....