# How to close underlying connections after catch httpwebrequest timeout

Tags: asp.net, httpwebrequest

My asp.net application sending httpwebrequest to remote REST server and waiting for the response, and I found there are lots of same error message like this:

> System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed-out.       at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

Is that possible that after I catch this exception and close the underlying http connection directly? or I don't really have to do so since I already set keepalive to false?

Thanks.

Actually another questions is if the timeout exception always happened at `System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse(),` does that mean application is waiting for the response from remote server and could not get response until time out. what could be the possible reason, network connection not stable? remote server not response? any other possible reasons?

Here is the code:

```
System.Net.HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = null;
System.IO.Stream stream  = null;
XmlTextReader xmlTextReader  = null;
try
{
    System.Net.HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(request);
    httpWebRequest.ReadWriteTimeout = 10000;
    httpWebRequest.Timeout = 10000;
    httpWebRequest.KeepAlive = false;
    httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
    httpWebResponse = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    stream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
    xmlTextReader = new  XmlTextReader(stream);
    xmlTextReader.Read();
    xmlDocument.Load(xmlTextReader);
    //Document processing code.
    //...
}
catch
{
    //Catch blcok with error handle
}
finally
{
    if (xmlTextReader != null)
        xmlTextReader.Close();
    if (httpWebResponse != null)
        httpWebResponse.Close();
    if (stream != null)
        stream.Close();
}
```

Comment: did you figure the solution? I am fight the same problem. I am out of ideas.

Comment: @AlekseyBykov you said, that the marked answer dont' solve your problem ? alternatives ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple rule-of-thumb is that if it doesn't implement IDisposal then it doesn't need disposing of.

Comment: did not implement IDisposal, but I found there are many connections in CLOSE_WAIT condition, not sure what happened, worried about if my code did not handle the underlying connections properly.

Comment: I think you have to trust the Framework designers on this one. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/716436/is-there-a-correct-way-to-dispose-of-a-httpwebrequest for more info.

Comment: even though in general it's true it doesn't solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

Also you could increase the number of outbound connections in the machine.config:

```
<system.net>
  <connectionManagement>
     <add address="*" maxconnection="2" />
  </connectionManagement>
</system.net>
```

Change the maxconnection attr to something higher, see:
http://www.williablog.net/williablog/post/2008/12/02/Increase-ASPNET-Scalability-Instantly.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to dispose as well as close.

Or use *using* blocks instead of *try-finally*:

```
using (var httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse()) {
    using (var stream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()) {
        using (var xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(stream)) {
            xmlDocument.Load(xmlTextReader);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One other thing you can do is call the Abort() method on an HTTPWebRequest that has resulted in an error, like so:

```
catch (WebException we)
{
    using (HttpWebResponse errorResp = we.Response as HttpWebResponse)
    {
    ...
    }
    request.Abort();
}
```