# How to check for FtpWebRequest timeout

Tags: c#, vb.net

How do I check for FtpWebRequest timeout

```
    Try

        Dim request As FtpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create("ftp://"), FtpWebRequest)
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails
        request.Timeout = 4000


        ' If 'TimeOut' = False Then

        request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("u", "p")
        Using response As FtpWebResponse = CType(request.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse)

            Using responseStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
                Using reader As New StreamReader(responseStream)

                    'do this

                End Using

            End Using

        End Using

        'End If

    Catch ex As Exception



    End Try
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can usually set the time out value and if there is no response for the said time ,a [WebException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ztey1y5b.aspx) is thrown with [status](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.status.aspx) property as Timeout.You can catch it and handle it appropriately.

```
  Try
    //your code for request/response
  Catch ex As WebException
    MsgBox("Exception reason "&ex.State)
  End Try
```

Comment: thanks - so if the exception happens then is the ftp requeset destroyed?

Comment: ftpwebrequest is like any other object and gc should reclaim the memory if it finds apt to do so.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/716436/is-there-a-correct-way-to-dispose-of-a-httpwebrequest