# C# Code keeps repeating

Tags: c#

I am trying to execute a code through a loop like this

```
for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
await Post(i,1,2,3);
MessageBox.Show("Success");
}
```

and the post method basically posts data to a certain website

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("Website");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.CookieContainer = cookie;
string datatowrite = i + "Some data"+ 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 //as string ofc
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(datatowrite);
request.ContentLength = data.Length;
using (Stream stream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync())
{
    await stream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

The loop executes well the first 2 times 
the third time it doesn't (It reaches the line with the Post() method then doesn't do anything doesn't even execute the message.

so I tried to place some breakpoints in the Post() method and found that
it keeps repeating it self multiple times (without any loops) and weirdly enough finally executes after and only after using the breakpoints .

PS. the methods works fine if I did it without looping like

```
Post(1,2,3,4);
Post(2,2,3,4);
Post(3,2,3,4);
```

etc
But I need to use the loop since x is entered by the user

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked it doesn't throw any exceptions?

Comment: Please make sure your sample code compiles. `for` must be lowercase

Comment: Make sure you are closing/disposing the http web request after it's finished.

Comment: @marko HttpWebRequest doesn't implement IDisposable - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/716436/is-there-a-correct-way-to-dispose-of-a-httpwebrequest

Comment: So the code you show works, but you also claim that _"x is entered by the user"_. If that's the only difference, the problem lies in the code that handles that. Show that code.

Comment: @marko Solved thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved

I wasn't closing the httpwebrequest after completeion using abort() method
thanks to Marko