# Clear context after HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

We use an HttpWebRequest to send query to a webservice with `NetworkCredential` like this :

```
Byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("...");
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.CreateHttp(strURL);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
request.ContentType = "application/xml";
request.Timeout = 10000;
request.KeepAlive = false;

NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential
{
    UserName = "...",
    Password = "..."
};

request.Credentials = cred;
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}

HttpWebResponse resp = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

To test it, we created a small console project with just this request and constant information (always the same).
After two successful requests, the third one systematically stops and ends in timeout.
But if we restart our application, we can immediately reissue two requests before the third one freezes again.

Do you have any idea of the cause?  It looks like some information needs to be purged before we can continue.

-- EDIT --
I tried to start each request on a separate thread (Using `Thread` or `Task`) with the same result.

Comment: Put the code in a using block so the request gets dispose when exiting.

Comment: @jdweng HttpWebRequest is not  IDisposable.  Where else do you suggest using a "using block" ?

Comment: It doesn't matter that HttpWebRequest is Disposable.  The using block pops the stack so the object is no longer used.

Comment: @jdweng Do you have an example of what you have in mind?

Comment: using(HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.CreateHttp(strURL)) { your code here }

Comment: @jdweng That's what I meant. This won't compile as HttpWebRequest doesn't implement IDisposable

Comment: The response and receive stream are so see following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716436/is-there-a-correct-way-to-dispose-of-a-httpwebrequest

Answer (score 0):

I change everything to use HttpClient and, now, everything works fine.